rsyslog stops accepting new connections
I have an rsyslog server configured to accept remote messages from around ~400 servers, however it seems once the server gets about ~256 connections it stops accepting new connections and the clients see error messages like the following
cannot connect to syslog.example.org:514: Connection timed out

The rsyslog imtcp module is configured as follows
module(load="imtcp"
          MaxSessions="1000"
          StreamDriver.Mode="1"
          StreamDriver.AuthMode="anon"
          StreamDriver.Name="gtls"

)

the systemd unit is also configured with LimitNOFILE=16384 and when i check /proc/$pid/limits i see that the number of limits looks good
$ /proc/2767537# cat limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             7393                 7393                 processes
Max open files            16384                16384                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       7393                 7393                 signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us

however when i start seeing this error the number of files in /proc/$pid/fd is close to 256.
/proc/2767537$ ls -l fd | wc -l
253

Further to this the established connections always close to 256
$ ss -ntp4 state established sport eq 514 | wc -l
257

this suggest to me that there is some other limit of 256 i need to tweak but im unable to find what/where.

I can't see any errors i the logs on the syslog server
using tcpdump I can see the syn packet come in on port 514 but no sys/ack is ever sent


This error seemed to be related to the following upstream issues

https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/318
https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/3770

upgrading to the most recent version of rsyslog on the ingest server resolved the issue
